# Can't generate lets-encrypt certificate using saltStack

Tags: salt-stack, lets-encrypt

I am trying to generate the lets-encrypt certificate and here are the steps that I followed:

- Under `/srv/salt/pillars/minion` I **added the file** `init.sls`

  ```
  letsencrypt: 
    config: |
      email = email
      auth:
        method: standalone
        type: http-01
        port: 8080
      agree-tos = True
      renew-by-default = True
    domainsets:
      mydomain:
        - mydomain.com
  ```

After that I **updated the salt_pillar**:

```
# . update_salt.sh
# salt 'minion' state.sls letsencrypt
```

I got this result:

```
ID: letsencrypt-crontab-mydomain.com
Function: cron.present
Name: /usr/local/bin/renew_letsencrypt_cert.sh mydomain.com
Result: False
Comment: One or more requisite failed: letsencrypt.domains.create-initial-
cert-mydomain.com
Started:
Duration:
Changes:
------------
ID: create-fullchain-privkey-pem-for-mydomain.com
Function: cmd.run
Name: cat /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/fullchain.pem \
       /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/privkey.pem \
       > /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/fullchain-privkey.pem && \ 
chmod 600 /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/fullchain-privkey.pem

Result: False
Comment: One or more requisite failed: letsencrypt.domains.create-initial-cert-mydomain.com
Started:
Duration:
Changes:
```

What should I modify in my configuration to get the certificate?

Comment: The information you provide is not complete. Please provide at least code / snippets from your `pillar/top.sls`, `salt/top.sls` and the mentioned `update_salt.sh`. With the current information we will not be able to help you.

Comment: What i want to know if the file **init.sls** is correct like that or not because i don't think that this issue related to top.sls or the update_salt.sh

Comment: From what I can see, it seems you're either using `letsencrypt` formula or you have another file called `letsencrypt.sls` somewhere in your states tree. Without this information it would be really hard to help you.